# VoiceOver doesn't scroll elements out of view properly

Tags: html, voiceover

HTML fixed footer with vertically scrolling content (standard stuff I hope, overflow:auto etc.).

When vertically scrolling through elements via right-swipe VoiceOver gesture as soon as VoiceOver focus hits the elements at the bottom of the visible view the VoiceOver focus moves through elements correctly but the scrollbar only scrolls half the element height hence the VoiceOver focus moves below the visible area.

**EDIT** Updated snippet, in previous one height of container was less that 50%, updated for clarity to show that the height doesn't matter.

Thanks in advance.

```css
.scrollContainer {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: auto;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 100px;
}

.rightData {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.stepData {
  padding: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.stepData > li {
  height: 42px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div style="height:500px;">
 <div id="container" class="scrollContainer">
        <ul class="stepData" style="padding:0px;">
            <li role="button" aria-label="date">06/01<span class="rightData" aria-label="steps">1001</span></li>
            <li role="button" aria-label="date">06/02<span class="rightData" aria-label="steps">1002</span></li>
            <li role="button">06/03<span class="rightData">1003</span></li>
            <li role="button">06/04<span class="rightData">1003</span></li>
            <li role="button">06/05<span class="rightData">1005</span></li>
            <li role="button">06/06<span class="rightData">1006</span></li>
            <li role="button">06/07<span class="rightData">1007</span></li>
            <li role="button">06/08<span class="rightData">1008</span></li>
            <li role="button">06/09<span class="rightData">1009</span></li>
            <li role="button">06/10<span class="rightData">1010</span></li>
            <li role="button">06/11<span class="rightData">1011</span></li>
            <li role="button">06/12<span class="rightData">1012</span></li>
            <li role="button">06/13<span class="rightData">1013</span></li>
            <li role="button">06/14<span class="rightData">1014</span></li>
            <li role="button">06/15<span class="rightData">1015</span></li>
            <li role="button">06/16<span class="rightData">1016</span></li>
            <li role="button">06/17<span class="rightData">1017</span></li>
            <li role="button">06/18<span class="rightData">1018</span></li>
            <li role="button">06/19<span class="rightData">1019</span></li>
            <li role="button">06/20<span class="rightData">1020</span></li>
            <li role="button">06/21<span class="rightData">1021</span></li>
            <li role="button">06/22<span class="rightData">1022</span></li>
            <li role="button">06/23<span class="rightData">1023</span></li>
            <li role="button">06/24<span class="rightData">1023</span></li>
            <li role="button">06/25<span class="rightData">1025</span></li>
            <li role="button">06/26<span class="rightData">1026</span></li>
            <li role="button">06/27<span class="rightData">1027</span></li>
            <li role="button">06/28<span class="rightData">1028</span></li>
            <li role="button">06/29<span class="rightData">1029</span></li>
            <li role="button">06/30<span class="rightData">1030</span></li>
            <li role="button">07/01<span class="rightData">1031</span></li>
            <li role="button">07/02<span class="rightData">1032</span></li>
            <li role="button">07/03<span class="rightData">1033</span></li>
            <li role="button">07/04<span class="rightData">1034</span></li>
            <li role="button">07/05<span class="rightData">1035</span></li>
            <li role="button">07/06<span class="rightData">1036</span></li>
            <li role="button">07/07<span class="rightData">1037</span></li>
            <li role="button">07/08<span class="rightData">1038</span></li>
            <li role="button">07/09<span class="rightData">1039</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    <p>
    footer
    </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick to making pages scrollable in Voiceover is to keep main content areas in the normal document flow using `position:relative`, not `absolute`. (I think overflow: hidden and max-height: 100% on the body element causes problems too, but I need to do more research.) The nav can use fixed positioning and slide in next to the rest of the content. One limitation is that a menu that also overflows the page height probably won’t scroll in Voiceover, as it will suffer from the original positioning bug.

Comment: Sorry, updated snippet to show that height doesn't matter.

Comment: Updated answer, I believe the problem is `position: absolute`

Comment: Trying to achieve a scrolling content area for which bottom of content area is above the bottom of the viewport.  So simple mark-up is having a container of a fixed height, overflow:scroll and then content which extends beyond the container height. This exhibits the VO issue (default position values). Any mark up which you could provide which you think should work would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether this helps but you can try [setting the VoiceOver focus manually](https://silvantroxler.ch/2016/setting-voiceover-focus-with-javascript/). If you're lucky, this might also scroll to the correct position.

If that does not work, you could try to use [`Element.scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) which should work in the latest versions of Safari Mobile. But I am not sure whether that also plays nicely with VoiceOver.

Comment: Thanks for the link, has helped on another issue I have. Right-swiping is causing VO to select elements and scroll so manually setting focus isn't an option, also (as far as I'm aware) it is not possible to get the VoiceOver focus in order call scrollIntoView (unless I'm missing something).